# How do I record live BBC radio using `get_iplayer`?

Tags: streaming, recording, internet-radio

I want to record the cricket from Five Live Sports Extra overnight so that I can listen to it tomorrow without a net connection.

I have installed `get_iplayer` (and `mplayer` and `ffmpeg` and `lame`).

I am having trouble understanding the manual.

I am using this command to record from Five Live (as Sports Extra is not broadcasting at this minute)

```
get_iplayer --liveradiomode realaudio2 --pid radio:bbc_radio_five_live --force
```

The `--liveradiomode` parameter is ignored, whatever I put there. `get_iplayer` attempts to download using `flashaacstd1` before downloading using `realaudio1`... but this downloads a 16second message informing me that the RealAudio stream no longer works.

I am using get_iplayer version 2.66-1, as packaged in Ubuntu Lucid 10.04.

**Edit:** This command is working for me to record Five Live:

```
get_iplayer --liveradiomode flashaac --amode=wma1 --pid radio:bbc_radio_five_live
```

So, problem solved :-)

Comment: Since you've solved your problem, write your answer as an answer rather than putting it in your question. This will make it easiers for others to find your solution. Also you can come back in two days (IIRC) and mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: +1 q,+1 a,+1 comment always good to find ways to record bbc streams

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
get_iplayer --liveradiomode flashaac --amode=wma1 --pid radio:bbc_radio_five_live
```